# Is it possible to see a list of which games I have marked as "Not Interested"?

Tags: steam

If, during processing your queue, you marked a game as "Not interested", but you later reconsider based on a better understanding of the game, can you undo the "Not Interested" mark somehow?

---

I know you can change it on the store page, but I'm also looking for a way to change them in bulk. For example: I could have marked an entire genre as "not interested" consistently, but after playing some games in that genre, I might be reconsidering that.

Comment: As far as I know, this only affects your queue. You can always buy or put the game in your wishlist at some later point, but it won't ever show up in your queue afterwards.

Comment: I've been able to change my selecting before moving on during the queue, and I *think* I've been able to navigate back to the game's store page and change it from there.

Comment: @Nolonar It will also no longer appear in your featured items list.

Comment: @originaluser you can change it on the store page, but I can't find an overview where you can change multiple at once.

Comment: You can already just click the link again to undo it. It sounds like you're more interesting in finding a list of the games you marked as Not Interested rather than what your initial question's title implied.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Go to http://store.steampowered.com/ (In your browser window NOT in steam.)
2. Log In
3. Go to http://store.steampowered.com/dynamicstore/userdata/ (refresh if blank)
4. Look for "rgIgnoredApps"
5. Look for the ID(s) to the Left of "rgIgnoredApps" Copy & Paste that id into this URL: store.steampowered.com/app/PUT_ID_HERE/

It's not possible to "Undo" them in bulk, however this should help make sure you haven't missed any along the way.

Answer (score 9):

The "Excluded Products" for your account are listed at https://store.steampowered.com/account/notinterested/

Answer (score 2):

Following @Sriahciboon 's answer, I wrote a small python script that does most of the work for you. [Here you go](https://gist.github.com/oryband/75301c063272b40354de). :)

This requires you to edit the script and know a bit of python though.

Comment: All it does is step #5 of Sriahchiboon's answer, that's nowhere near "most of the work".

Comment: @RossRidge well yes, but this most time-consuming step - loading each app id and finding out which game is it. This is practically an id-to-game-name converter.

Comment: Your script is pretty cool. It allowed me to check the names of games at [the intersection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/642919) of games owned and games marked as "not interested".

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Carl Reinke's answer for the Steam website, here is one **applicable to the Steam program**:

Go to *Store* -> *Explore*, scroll down a little until you see *Your Queue Activity*, and select *View titles marked not interested* under the lowest category *Not Interested*.

[image: Display titles you're not interested in in Steam]

On the following page, you have a simple list of all the titles you marked as 'Not Interested', and scrolling over them reveals **a button you can click to delete them** from this list:

[image: Delete titles from the list by using the button marked 'X']

Comment: Why was this downvoted? A little feedback, please.